# Why the SQL engine scan the whole table on a index column while using LIMIT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key, sql-execution-plan

I have a SQL query like:

```
select *
from customers
where customer_id > 0
order by customer_id asc
limit 500;
```

And the customer_id is the primary key of the customers table. When I execute this query and check the execution plan. I saw it scans the whole table:

```
SELECT (select)     500 23.0    0.0 Node Type = Limit;
Parallel Aware = false;
Startup Cost = 0.43;
Total Cost = 23.16;
Plan Rows = 500;
Plan Width = 237;

TRANSFORM (Limit)       500 23.0    0.0 Node Type = Limit;
Parallel Aware = false;
Startup Cost = 0.43;
Total Cost = 23.16;
Plan Rows = 500;
Plan Width = 237;

INDEX_SCAN (Index Scan)  table: customers; index: pk12; 3262339 148316.0    0.0 Node Type = Index Scan;
Parent Relationship = Outer;
Parallel Aware = false;
Scan Direction = Forward;
Index Name = pk12;
Relation Name = customers;
Alias = customers;
Startup Cost = 0.43;
Total Cost = 148316.36;
Plan Rows = 3222222;
Plan Width = 237;
Index Cond = (customer_id > '0'::numeric);
```

In my intuition, the primary key would have index created and the sql engine could just locate the lower bound and get 500 items from the leaf nodes of the index (b+ tree). This is the quickest execution plan I can think of. Why does the sql engine scan the whole DB table and sort it first to get only 500 items?

PS: PostgreSQL.

Comment: Noting the `'0'::numeric` on the index scan, is the id column a numeric type?  This may also be an issue of statistics.  Has autovacuum been disabled?  Try `ANALYZE <table_name>;` to collect statistics about that specific table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is just the estimated cost and number of rows for the *complete* index scan, but as you can see, PostgreSQL is aware that it does not have to scan the complete index, else the estimated total cost of the query (23.16) could not be less than the estimated cost of the index scan (148316.36).

Use `EXPLAIN (ANAYLZE)` to see what *actually* happens:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id) AS SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 100000);
ALTER TABLE test ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
VACUUM (ANALYZE) test;
```

I have stripped the irrelevant lines from the execution plan:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, FORMAT json)
   SELECT id FROM test WHERE id > 0 ORDER BY id LIMIT 500;

                  QUERY PLAN                   
-----------------------------------------------
 [                                            +
   {                                          +
     "Plan": {                                +
       "Node Type": "Limit",                  +
       "Startup Cost": 0.29,                  +
       "Total Cost": 14.56,                   +
       "Plan Rows": 500,                      +
       "Actual Rows": 500,                    +
       "Plans": [                             +
         {                                    +
           "Node Type": "Index Only Scan",    +
           "Index Name": "test_pkey",         +
           "Plan Rows": 100000,               +
           "Actual Rows": 500,                +
           "Index Cond": "(id > 0)",          +
         }                                    +
       ]                                      +
     },                                       +
   }                                          +
 ]
(1 row)
```

So the index scan is stopped after the first 500 rows have been found.